# GSL Compile error with MINGW

Tags: mingw, gsl

Followed instructions from a prior post for installing GSL and compiling (mingw running from DevKit)

```
wget ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gsl/gsl-1.15.tar.gz
tar xf gsl*
cd gsl*
./configure
# Warning, make takes about 7 min.
make
make install
```

everything appears to run up to a point then a compile error occurs during the make

```
$ make
/usr/Bin/make  all-recursive
make[1]: Entering directory `/c/cygwin/home/Seamus/gsl-1.15'
Making all in gsl
make[2]: Entering directory `/c/cygwin/home/Seamus/gsl-1.15/gsl'
rm -f gsl*.h
HEADERLIST="../gsl*.h ../*/gsl*.h"; \
        for h in $HEADERLIST; do \
          BASENAME=`basename $h`; \
          test -r $BASENAME || ln -s $h $BASENAME; \
        done
make[2]: Leaving directory `/c/cygwin/home/Seamus/gsl-1.15/gsl'
Making all in utils
make[2]: Entering directory `/c/cygwin/home/Seamus/gsl-1.15/utils'
/bin/sh ../libtool --tag=CC   --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..     -g                         -O2 -MT placeholder.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/placeholder.Tpo -c -o placeholder.lo p                        laceholder.c
libtool: compile:  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I.. -g -O2 -MT placeholder.lo -MD -M                        P -MF .deps/placeholder.Tpo -c placeholder.c  -DDLL_EXPORT -DPIC -o .libs/placeh                        older.o
libtool: compile:  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I.. -g -O2 -MT placeholder.lo -MD -M                        P -MF .deps/placeholder.Tpo -c placeholder.c -o placeholder.o >/dev/null 2>&1
mv -f .deps/placeholder.Tpo .deps/placeholder.Plo
/bin/sh ../libtool --tag=CC   --mode=link gcc  -g -O2   -o libutils.la  placehol                        der.lo  -lm
libtool: link: ar cru .libs/libutils.a .libs/placeholder.o
libtool: link: ranlib .libs/libutils.a
libtool: link: ( cd ".libs" && rm -f "libutils.la" && ln -s "../libutils.la" "li                        butils.la" )
make[2]: Leaving directory `/c/cygwin/home/Seamus/gsl-1.15/utils'
Making all in sys
make[2]: Entering directory `/c/cygwin/home/Seamus/gsl-1.15/sys'
/bin/sh ../libtool --tag=CC   --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I.. -I..                            -g -O2 -MT minmax.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/minmax.Tpo -c -o minmax.lo minmax.c
libtool: compile:  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I.. -I.. -g -O2 -MT minmax.lo -MD -M                        P -MF .deps/minmax.Tpo -c minmax.c  -DDLL_EXPORT -DPIC -o .libs/minmax.o
In file included from minmax.c:26:0:
../gsl/gsl_minmax.h:1:1: error: expected identifier or '(' before '!' token
../gsl/gsl_minmax.h:1:1: error: stray '\377' in program
../gsl/gsl_minmax.h:1:1: error: stray '\376' in program
../gsl/gsl_minmax.h:1:14: warning: null character(s) ignored
../gsl/gsl_minmax.h:1:16: warning: null character(s) ignored
../gsl/gsl_minmax.h:1:18: warning: null character(s) ignored
../gsl/gsl_minmax.h:1:20: warning: null character(s) ignored
../gsl/gsl_minmax.h:1:22: warning: null character(s) ignored
../gsl/gsl_minmax.h:1:24: warning: null character(s) ignored
../gsl/gsl_minmax.h:1:26: warning: null character(s) ignored
../gsl/gsl_minmax.h:1:28: warning: null character(s) ignored
../gsl/gsl_minmax.h:1:30: warning: null character(s) ignored
../gsl/gsl_minmax.h:1:32: warning: null character(s) ignored
../gsl/gsl_minmax.h:1:34: warning: null character(s) ignored
../gsl/gsl_minmax.h:1:36: warning: null character(s) ignored
../gsl/gsl_minmax.h:1:38: warning: null character(s) ignored
../gsl/gsl_minmax.h:1:40: warning: null character(s) ignored
../gsl/gsl_minmax.h:1:42: warning: null character(s) ignored
make[2]: *** [minmax.lo] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/c/cygwin/home/Seamus/gsl-1.15/sys'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/c/cygwin/home/Seamus/gsl-1.15'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Any thoughts would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Re-did installation from scratch using fresh MinGW and MSYS from http://www.mingw.org/wiki/Getting_Started with full installation (took a little bit of playing around as the first pass only seemed to download but not actually install). Added paths to windows environment as described on the page (for MSYS and MinGW). Then to start the shell opened a windows CMD and ran the C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\msys.bat file.

Then followed the detailed instructions (ignoring the Dev-C++ IDE, etc... for windows and just focusing on the GSL and MinGW compile) for downloading, installing and compiling the GSL libraries from http://www.ph.utexas.edu/~daneel/GSL_devcpp.html (thanks daneel@utexas.edu) - no issues in compiling or build.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem cross compiling GSL for an STM32 target. I was using cygwin in Windows 7 and to fix the issue I forced cygwin to use native symlinks exporting variable CYGWIN=winsymlinks:nativestrict